# Changing Locale in Docker Stops Many Commands From Executing?

Tags: ruby, linux, shell, docker, ubuntu-16.04

**How come when I change my locale in  a Dockerfile using this...**:

```
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

**...so that I can achieve a change in locale from this...**

```
LANG=  
LANGUAGE=  
LC_CTYPE="POSIX"  
LC_NUMERIC="POSIX"  
LC_TIME="POSIX"  
LC_COLLATE="POSIX"  
LC_MONETARY="POSIX"  
LC_MESSAGES="POSIX"  
LC_PAPER="POSIX"  
LC_NAME="POSIX"  
LC_ADDRESS="POSIX"  
LC_TELEPHONE="POSIX"  
LC_MEASUREMENT="POSIX"  
LC_IDENTIFICATION="POSIX"  
LC_ALL=
```

**..to this..**

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8  
LANGUAGE=en_US:en  
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"  
LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

**Then I get issues**, such as this with no commands executing:

`root@820760edeb77:/# irb
bash: irb: command not found`

**But if I take those changes to the locale, and leave them as they are after a rebuilt container, then everything works as expected??:**

```
# ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
# ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
# ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

`root@820760edeb77:/# irb
2.3.1 :001 >`

*I'm not too sure what would be causing this issue, whereby the changed locale inhibits commands from working, but suspect this could just be a side effect of such a change in Locale within the Docker container, and possibly not the real issue?*

Comment: can you post the 2 Dockerfiles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I just figured it out, turns out I was using the wrong locale type for Docker, which is related to this issue [here](https://github.com/docker-library/docs/pull/689/commits/c065de3b2446a2ddbe8c9afd6fb6a96d93dbbad6).

A small, but critical distinction `C` vs `en_US`:

**`WRONG`**

```
ENV LANG en_US.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE en_US:en
ENV LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8
```

**`RIGHT`**

```
ENV LANG C.UTF-8
ENV LANGUAGE C.UTF-8
ENV LC_ALL C.UTF-8
```

Can anyone tell me why Docker uses `C` as a locale, vs `en_US`, or any other?

Now Ruby/`irb` is successfully working (**albeit, with 4 hours of my life lost.....**)

Comment: I wish I can upvote this 100 times more. Thank you